# how to make a logical exclusion within the query?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have 3 tables in our ERP database holding all delivery data (table documents holds one row for each delivery note, `documentpos` holds all positions on delivery notes, `documentserialnumbers` holds all serial numbers for delivered items).
I want to show all items with their serial number that have been delivered to the customer and still resides there so far.
The above shown output of the following query however shows, that one item that has been delivered was returned (red marks) later. The return delivery note has the document number 527419 (dark red mark) and refers to the the delivery note 319821 (green) which is listed yellow.
The correct list would consequential show only items that are still on customer's site without the returned items (see below).
**How do I have to change the query in order to exclude the returned items from the output?**

The upper table shows in the image shows the output of my query, the table below how it should be.

```
select a.BelID, c.ReferenzBelID, a.itemnumber, a.itemname, c.deliverynotenumber,c.documenttype, c.documentmark, b.serialnumber
from dbo.documentpos a 
inner join dbo.documentserialnumbers b on a.BelPosID = b.BelPosID 
inner join dbo.documents c on a.BelID = c.BelID 
inner join sysdba.customers d on d.account = c.A0Name1
where  d.AccountID = 'customername' and c.documenttype like '%delivery%'  
order by a.BelID
```

[image: wrong and wanted output]

Comment: Is there only one way to exclude the rows i.e. documenttype = 'return delivery note'.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask]. Please read the first three paragraphs of the [tsql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tsql/info) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may exclude positions, which are referenced by any "return" delivery note, like this (edited)

```
select a.BelID, c.ReferenzBelID, a.itemnumber, a.itemname, c.deliverynotenumber,c.documenttype, c.documentmark, b.serialnumber
from dbo.documentpos a 
inner join dbo.documentserialnumbers b on a.BelPosID = b.BelPosID 
inner join dbo.documents c on a.BelID = c.BelID 
inner join sysdba.customers d on d.account = c.A0Name1
where  d.AccountID = 'customername' and c.documenttype like '%delivery%'
and not exists (select 1 
                from dbo.documents cc
                where cc.documenttype like '%delivery%' 
                and c.ReferenzBelID=cc.BelID
                and c.documentmark='VLR')
and not exists (select 1
                from dbo.documents ccc
                join dbo.documentpos aa on aa.BelID = ccc.BelID 
                where ccc.ReferenzBelID=c.BelID
                and ccc.documentmark='VLR'
                and a.itemnumber=aa.itemnumber)
order by a.BelID
```

Comment: I tried that, Dmitriy, but adding this line eliminates alle rows with BelID = 319821. But only the delivery notes with the serial number "xxxG900025" should be excluded. Wouldn't it be better to find a way to exclude those rows with multiple serial numbers? I'm trying to create a temporary table and then add a query that shows only those lines which have only one serial number. But I cannot find the right syntax to do it in one query.

Comment: No change after adding your code - the result ist the same as without it

Comment: sorry, I've made a typo... please try again, it should work now

Comment: Now your code eliminates the line with the return delivery note - half way is done. But the corresponding delivered item is still listed. I would prefer showing only rows  with only one serial number. All rows with more than one serial numbers hold items that have been returned and are no more on customer's site.

Comment: Yes, well done Dmitriy! I only added another join to point to Serialnumber instead of the item number, just to avoid situations in which erroneously different items have the same item number:

Comment: `and not exists (select 1
                from dbo.documents ccc
                join dbo.documentpos aa on aa.BelID = ccc.BelID 
  join dbo.documentserialnumbers L on L.BelPosID = aa.BelPosID                
  where ccc.ReferenzBelID=c.BelID
                and ccc.documentmark='VLR'
                and b.Serialnumber=L.Serialnumber)
order by b.BelID`